# Remove a class added conditionally using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I add a class `another-class` based on condition as follows using `ng-class`.Is it possible to remove that `another-class` using `ng-class` when the condition is not met? Right now the class `another-class` just remains in the element even when the condition is not met!

```
<div ng-hide="ok.isTrue" ng-class = "'{{ok.Id}}' === '{{notok.Id}}' ? 'another-class': '' ;" class="some-class">
```

Comment: Bookmark this page for syntax: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use different `ng-class` syntax for this, particularly the map syntax:

```
ng-class="{'another-class': ok.Id === notok.Id}"
```

Comment: So this adds `another-class` when the condition is met.. Next time if the condition is not met is there a way to remove the already added `another-class` ?

Comment: it's a test... when the test results false, the "another-class" will be removed by angular. You don't need care about that, only trust.

Comment: Still doesn't work in my code although i noticed for some reason i don't see `ng-binding` as class attribute. Could that be a reason?

Comment: @prem89 please provide more of your code, a [MVCE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/454533) would be helpful